# How to iterate/loop through multiple numbered variables in R

Tags: r, loops, variables, for-loop, matrix

So, I'm new to programming in R, so I don't even know if this is feasible to even do. I have 50 matrices (50,000 rows by 10 columns) I'm trying to populate for a Monte Carlo simulation. I created all matrices in a loop and they're called `mCMatrix1`, `mCMatrix2` etc.

I want to populate the matrices in a loop, something to this effect:

```
for (i in 50){
for (j in 50000){
    num <- mu + tR %*% rnorm(10) # returns a 10 row, 1 column matrix
    mCMatrixC"i"[]= num[,1] # basically rotates the matrix to fill in the first row
}
}
```

where I can somehow code the program to know that it needs to populate `mCMatrix1`, then `mCMatrix2`, all the way to the 50th matrix. For STATA users, I remember you could loop through variables with with v = forval(range of values), mCMatrix`v' . (It's been a while since I've used STATA, so the syntax probably isn't right, but it was something to that effect.

Comment: how are you using j? it would be better to keep them in a list rather than having 50+ objects in your workspace, like `mlist <- replicate(50, list(matrix(rnorm(50000 * 10), ncol = 10)))` where `replicate` is a loop creating a 50000 x 10 matrix of whatever values you want and returning a list of length 50

Answer (score 0):

R runs on lists and data.frames which is a little bit different from other methods.  Your easiest method is to create a list of of matrix names and iterate through the list.

Rawr's approach is the simplest and probably most effective.

Then you simply access it by mlist[n], n being the matrix you want.

If you want a complete data frame approach its a little more complicated but it gives a data table with indices rather than a list of matrices

```
library(dplyr)
yourData <- data.frame()

for (k in 1:50) {
  yourData <- yourData %>% 
    rbind((as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(50000 * 10), nrow=50000, ncol=10))) %>%    
    mutate(Run = k))
}
```

That way you could access it as

```
yourData %>% filter(Run = n)
```

Comment: i dont think you tested this at all

Comment: The first time I did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of matrices for easier access and access it using the following. I am not sure about the matrix operation you do in the loop so I have chosen a random matrix as an example.

```
> list_matrices = c()
> for (i in 1:10) { list_matrices[[i]] = matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3)}
> list_matrices[[1]]
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.09855292  0.2665513  0.72873888
[2,] -0.03005994 -0.4834303 -1.12356622
[3,]  0.98443875  0.5895932  0.07072777
```

Answer (score 0):

If the core issue is to generate new (numbered)  variable names and assign values to them, then I think you can use this approach:

```
for(i in 1:3) 
{
n<- sprintf("matr%d",i)
print(n)
assign(x=n,value = i)
}
matr1
matr2
matr3
```